# HOW TO FIX The following classes could not be found: - android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio and I am fetching this error

```
The following classes could not be found:- android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView"
```

Here is the screenshot from my Android Studio IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` to dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a support design dependency to app level  `build.gradle` ? If not, then add the following dependency to Module: app level `build.gradle`.
dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:version'
```